# Narrator. Scan Mode. Key Press Events

Tags: c#, xaml, events, uwp, narrator

I have many items with the events: "`Tapped`", "`KeyUp`", "`KeyDown`".

**Example:**

```
<GridView KeyDown="OnKeyDown"
          Tapped="OnTapped"
          KeyUp="OnKeyUp">
```

In the normal mode of the Narrator, pressing the enter and space keys triggers events, but in scan mode the Narrator ignore them.

This behavior is occurs to the use of these keyboard keys (`Enter`, `Space`, etc.) in the hot keys of the Narrator:

[Windows10 Narrator keyboard commands](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22806/windows-10-narrator-keyboard-commands-touch-gestures).

How can I send click events to the `Enter` and `Space` keys in `Scan Mode`?

Answer (score 0):

> In the normal mode of the Narrator, pressing the enter and space keys triggers events, but in scan mode the Narrator ignore them.

Since `Navigation` is system level, you can't close it in your uwp app. If you do not use scan mode, the `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` event will be responded correctly to keyboard input.

Scan mode is not always in the open state. It will turn off when you switch to a different app. In other words, scan mode is off when you open your uwp app. And the keyboard events work well, unless you manually open scan mode. You could press `Caps lock` + `Spacebar` to turn it off again, and the keyboards event will work.

For more details, you could refer to [Using scan mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22809).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I want to influence the interaction between the Narrator and my UWP app. Currently, Scanning Mode violates the process of user interacting with my app and I can't do anything.